# jquery hide/overlay video player

Tags: jquery

I've got a dynamically built html table from the server.  Ultimately it gives me a table that looks like:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<table id="webcam-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Camera Name</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>             
            <tr >
                <td onclick="DoNav('http://myserver.com:1935/recordings/myfile1.mp4');">
                    Default camera 
                </td>
                <td onclick="DoNav('http://myserver:1935/recordings/myfile1.mp4');">
                    06 May 2012 07:25:01 
                </td>
                </tr>

            <tr >
                <td onclick="DoNav('http://myserver.com:1935/recordings/myfile2.mp4');">
                    Default camera 
                </td>
                <td onclick="DoNav('http://myserver.com:1935/recordings/myfile2.mp4');">
                    06 May 2012 07:24:47 
                </td>
                </tr>
...
</tbody></table>
```

If anyone clicks the row on the table it calls the DoNav function to insert a video.

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
{
var mydiv = $("#player");
var myvideo = $("<video id='myfileplayer' src='"+ theUrl +"' width='280' height='200' controls></video>");
mydiv.append(myvideo);
$("#myfileplayer").click(function(){
    $(this).play();
});

}
```

It plays great if you click on one row in the table.  But once you click on the next row it adds another player underneath and so on.  I want to replace the player that is there with the new one that was just clicked.  I've tried adding `$("#myfileplayer").hide();` to the end of the `DoNav` function but that just hides the player overall.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending a new player underneath the previous one.

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
{

    // only add the player if it doesn't yet exist
    if($('#myfileplayer').length == 0) {
        var mydiv = $("#player");
        var myvideo = $("<video id='myfileplayer' src='"+ theUrl +
           "' width='280' height='200'  controls></video>");
        mydiv.append(myvideo);
    } else {
       $('#myfileplayer').attr("src",theUrl); 
    }

    $("#myfileplayer").click(function(){
        $(this).play();
    });

}
```

Comment: Is replacing the src attribute on an already existing element somehow more intensive than replacing the entire player? Does the downvoter want to come out of hiding and possibly elaborate on why he/she thinks this is so bad? Thanks!

Comment: This worked great, also adding +1 as I can't imagine why someone would down vote to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

this is simple, in your DoNav function, replace

```
mydiv.append(myvideo);
```

with:

```
mydiv.html(myvideo);
```

What this does is that it replaces the content (the old video) in the video div instead of just adding a new video to the div.

Comment: This didn't work for me. This is geared towards iDevices, don't know if that makes a difference.